# Other processes won't be woken up using semaphore

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, semaphore

The following code is from [Wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Operating_System_Design/Processes/Semaphores).

```
wait(Semaphore s){
    s=s-1;
    if (s<0) {
        // add process to queue
        block();
    }
}

signal(Semaphore s){
    s=s+1;
    if (s>=0) {
        // remove process p from queue
        wakeup(p);
    }
}
```

What if I have more than 2 process while the capacity is 1 (`s` is initialized to 1)? For example, Process 1 enters the critical session. Then Process 2 and 3 invoke `wait`. `s` equals -2 now. Then Process 1 finishes and invokes `signal`. `s` becomes -1. Since `s >= 0` won't be satisfied, Process 2 and 3 would never be woken up. What's the problem here?

Comment: The code is wrong, it must be `if (s <= 0) {wakeup(p)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)

as opposed to the wiki books link.

In the wiki article and Windows, semaphores are zero or have a positive count, and could be implemented using unsigned integers for the count. The wait function for a semaphore does not decrement the semaphore if it is already zero, instead it just waits. If multiple processes or threads are waiting for a semaphore with count == 0, then if the semaphore is incremented by 1, only one of the processes or threads will be woke up (and the semaphore decremented back to zero), and it is operating system dependent for which one will be woke up.

Link to Windows semaphore description with additional links to semaphore functions.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129(v=vs.85).aspx